# ADF LoV Switching

Tags: java, oracle-adf, lov

I have View Object that I use of two different jsf pages. Each jsf has his own Data Model in the AppModel. I want to use different LoV for an attribute from the VO in each jsf (not based on a condition - simply one Lov for the first page and the other LoV for the second page).

Which is the optimal way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

create two view criteria's for the View object. Define your LOV's based on these view criteria's. If there is no condition, just pass null as a bind variable(make sure `accept null values` is set to `true` or `checked`). This will get you two sets of Lov's

Answer (score 0):

You can specify two LOV's on the attribute and then use `LOV switcher` property to switch between the LOV's based on a condition.

http://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2008/12/groovy-multiple-lovs-per-attribute-in.html
http://www.awasthiashish.com/2015/02/adf-basics-set-multiple-lovs-on.html

Or, if you do not want to use conditional switching of LOV's then add a duplicate attribute, which represents the same EO attribute or the same database column, depending upon if the VO is editable or readonly, in your VO. Now you can assign  different LOV's to the original and its duplicate and then use these LOV attributes separately.